# Whats the easiest way to remove from an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

```
var myLetters = new Array(
         new BlockA(),
         new BlockB(),
         new BlockC()
    );
```

How can i remove myLetters[1] for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To remove an element at an arbitrary position you can use splice http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29:

```
myLetters.splice(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

What about [`.splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000752.html)?

If you want to remove the first element:

```
myLetters.splice(0, 1);
```

Where the first argument is the index (starting from 0) and the second is the amount of items you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

delete myLetters[1]; would also work, except it does not move items after [1] to close the gap.